# Improve the following VBScript share drive output to txt

Tags: network-shares, vbscript, sharing

I'm using the following VBScript to generate current share drive for users
I would like to improve the efficiency of the MappedDrives.txt

Now the output is like this

```
H: (\\singsfile03\apps)
I: (\\singsfile03\IT Information)
```

**Question 1:**

I would like the output of text file to have this way of formatting so I could save it as bat file

```
NET USE H: "\\singsfile03\apps"
NET USE I: "\\singsfile03\IT Information"
```

**Question 2:**

How do I alter the output to have inactive shared drive as well as those which are active?

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(".\MappedDrives.txt")

Set colDrives = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 4")

For Each objDrive in colDrives
    objOutFile.WriteLine(objDrive.DeviceID & " (" & _
      objDrive.ProviderName & ")")
Next

objOutFile.Close
```

Comment: Hi, anyone has an answer on this question

Comment: I gave you an answer to Q1 but you did not respond.

Comment: Hi Michael, I did, but I'm not sure why the StackExchange seem to be having delay of message

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Just make the VBScript output the strings you want, in the For Each part.

```
objOutFile.WriteLine("NET USE " & objDrive.DeviceID & " " &  chr(34) & _
      objDrive.ProviderName & chr(34))
```

On my system

Before:

```
H: (\\rpi4\share2)
Z: (\\192.168.0.12\share)
```

After:

```
NET USE H: "\\rpi4\share2"
NET USE Z: "\\192.168.0.12\share"
```

Comment: thank you this worked!

Comment: But this does not save those inactive/disconnected shared drive in regards for my question 2, if I used net use output to text I could see the unavailable  drive